# SASS vs. CSS attributes including concatenated classes

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

here is a sample of some CSS that is compiled by SASS:

```
#affinity-page.header.slide.hasSubnav {
  height: 50px;
}
```

the question I have is, is the multiple concatenated periods a SASS element or a native CSS selector method?  If it's native CSS I'm wondering, does it mean, "Having this id, AND this class, AND this class, etc." ?  Thanks

Comment: That's exactly what it means. This is why you shouldn't learn SASS _before_ learning CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If it's native CSS I'm wondering, does it mean, "Having this id, AND
>   this class, AND this class, etc."?

Yes.

This may clarify a bit: https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/

Comment: Accepted, I realized after that I could find answer by searching for "CSS require 2 classes" or "CSS require multiple classes" and confirmed it.